# Working with words, and need to translate ABC to Alpha, Bravo, Charlie

Tags: python

Im very new to Python, and im trying to do some Simple Python Exercises, from this link:
http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/python_exercises.html

But im having problems with number 35. at the moment.

What i need to do is make a small program that will speak out what i type in: But all the a's will be said as Alpha, all the b's will be said as Bravo, all the c's will be said as Charlie and so on..

I have been provided with this to help me going:

```
d = {'a':'alfa', 'b':'bravo', 'c':'charlie', 'd':'delta', 'e':'echo', 'f':'foxtrot',
 'g':'golf', 'h':'hotel', 'i':'india', 'j':'juliett', 'k':'kilo', 'l':'lima',
 'm':'mike', 'n':'november', 'o':'oscar', 'p':'papa', 'q':'quebec', 'r':'romeo',
 's':'sierra', 't':'tango', 'u':'uniform', 'v':'victor', 'w':'whiskey', 
 'x':'x-ray', 'y':'yankee', 'z':'zulu'}
```

What i have made so far is this:

```
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.speak("Hello.. Please write a line. You want me to say")
print ("Type your text now:") 
d = input()
print ("Outputting...")
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.speak (d)
```

And this is working as intented, it will speak out what i type. But can any one help me to figure out how how to implement so it will work as described above?

All help will be much appreciate. Please keep in mind that im very new to this.

Comment: `d` is a dictionary - http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html# - you should able to go from there...

Comment: If you have any specific problem, please describe it. Otherwise it looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own.

Comment: I hear you, and i had tried to solve this on my own. Sorry if it looked like i just want the soluton, that was not the whole point. Im very new to Python, and coding in general. So im in the beginning of the learning phase. So different solutions and explenations will help me to understand this better. But you are right, and i value your input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a dictionary of it already, just loop through the string and use the keys:

```
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

d = {'a':'alfa', 'b':'bravo', 'c':'charlie', 'd':'delta', 'e':'echo', 'f':'foxtrot',
 'g':'golf', 'h':'hotel', 'i':'india', 'j':'juliett', 'k':'kilo', 'l':'lima',
 'm':'mike', 'n':'november', 'o':'oscar', 'p':'papa', 'q':'quebec', 'r':'romeo',
 's':'sierra', 't':'tango', 'u':'uniform', 'v':'victor', 'w':'whiskey', 
 'x':'x-ray', 'y':'yankee', 'z':'zulu'}
speaker.speak("Hello.. Please write a line you want me to say")
print ("Type your text now:")
inp = input()
print ("Outputting...")
result = ' '.join(d[c.lower()] for c in inp)
speaker.speak(result)
```

There you go, hope this helps!

Comment: This was the perfekt solution, just what i needed. I simply could not see my way through it, but now i see. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would not use this solutions because it calls the speaker.speak multiple times, thou it propably does not matter it migt not be as good as if you pass the whole string - the function might have some inner workings so it deals with contionus text naturally and it might sound better...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you need to really understand what your inputs and outputs are, and what transformations are needed.

You are provided with a dictionnary `d` which is like a phone-book : it maps two types of data (in the case of a phone-book, the name of a person and it's phone number).

`res = input()` is a function which will return (and store into `res` ) what the user types in.

`speaker.speak ( w )` will enunciate the word `w` provided as input

So basically you need to transform `res` using `d` and the output of the transformation will serve as input for `speaker.speak`

Hint : `output = d[input]` return the mapping of input un

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me. The way you describe it here, givd me much more meaning, and a better understanding of it all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Umm what about this:

```
>>> print ' '.join(d[letter.lower()] for letter in list(raw_input('Type your text now: ')))
Type your text now: Python
papa yankee tango hotel oscar november
```

(If you just use this as input to speaker.speak you should be fine.)

I know it's one liner but you can split it for yourself quite easily..

Comment: Good answer. Two things I have to mention: If `letter` is whitespace or something else it throws an Exception so I would suggest `d.get(letter.lower(), letter)`. The second thing: you can iterate directly on the result of `raw_input`. There is no need for using a `list`, is there?

Comment: Yeah you definitely do not need to use list. I think I just wanted to explicitly show what is happening.